# Escape encoding of liquid tags in Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, liquid, liquid-layout

We are using Nokogiri gem and the html we get from the test editor is saved using Nokogiri `Nokogiri::HTML::fragment(html_text).to_html` converts into proper html tags and is getting saved to the database. But we are having some liquid tags which when rendered substitutes the value in the place where tags are added.

**eg. html code snippet**

```
<body>
  <div>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.Dolorem quam itaque, dolore esse labore dolorum inventore optio earum iure explicabo impedit eveniet perspiciatis nobis vero culpa aliquid, iusto saepe sunt.</p>
    <a href="http://some_link">{{some_link}}</a>
    <div>
      <a href="{{payment_link}}">{{payment_link}}</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

once we convert it into the html tags using nokogiri it gets text in the url gets encoded(`href="{{payment_link}}"`). Is there a way to escape url encoding for the liquid tags?

This is how the html code when rendered and saved looks like in db

**Output data**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do  eiusmod<br>\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br>\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br>\nconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br>\ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br>\nproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\n\n<p> </p>\n\n<p><a href=\"http://%7B%7Bpayment_link%7D%7D\">{{payment_link}}</a></p>"
```

**Expected data**

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do  eiusmod<br>\ntempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,<br>\nquis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo<br>\nconsequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse<br>\ncillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non<br>\nproident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>\n\n<p> </p>\n\n<p><a href=\"{{payment_link}}">{{payment_link}}</a></p>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]", including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]". We need to see evidence of your effort, in this case, code showing your attempt at solving the problem. Without that it looks like you're asking us to write the code for you.

Comment: To answer your question, no, Nokogiri can't do that. It's a HTML/XML parser and has no knowledge of markup outside HTML/XML, nor should it. You could preprocess the template and fill in those values before handing it to Nokogiri, or you can post-process it and undo the encoding.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the reply. Next time I will keep in mind while posting

Comment: Hey, I know this is old, but wondering if you found any kind of solution for this? Having the same issue.